# Passing link parameters MVC and JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass multiple links with their own parameters to controller from View  But I get null values  parsed to the controller.  Below are the salient code snippets any help will be highly appreciated.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<a href="#?id=@item.Id&un=@item.ReceiverUn" class="list-group-item active myajaxlink" >
<span class="label label-inverse pull-right">@item.InOn</span>
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">@item.SenderUn @item.Subject<i class="fa fa-flag     text-primary"></i></h4>
<p class="margin-none">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Body)</p>
</a>}
```

Below is the Javascript With Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#animatedgif").hide();
            $(".myajaxlink").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/InMail/check",
                type: "POST",
                data: { id: $('#id').val(), un: $('#un').val() }
            }).done(function () {

            }).complete(function (){
                $("#animatedgif").hide();
            }).success(function (dv) {
                $(".email-content").replaceWith(dv);
            });
        });
    });
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $("#animatedgif").show();
    }).ajaxSuccess(function () {
        $("#animatedgif").hide();
    });

    function myonbegin() {
        //show animated gif
        //alert("helloworld");
        $("#animatedgif").show();
    }
    function myonsuccess() {
        //disable animated gif
        $("#animatedgif").hide();
    }
    function myonfailure() {
        //disbale animated gif
        $("#animatedgif").hide();
    }
    function myoncomplete() {
        //disable animated gif
        $("#animatedgif").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get null because `$('#id').val()` and `$('#un').val()` return null. This happens [because](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) this `$('#id').val()` construction searches element on the page with attribute id="id" and for #un - id="un". 

To achive what you need you can simply add following modifications:

**Razor:**

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
   <a href="#" data-id="@item.Id" data-un="@item.ReceiverUn" class="list-group-item active myajaxlink" >
   <span class="label label-inverse pull-right">@item.InOn</span>
   <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">@item.SenderUn @item.Subject<i class="fa fa-flag     text-primary"></i></h4>
   <p class="margin-none">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Body)</p>
   </a>
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".myajaxlink").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var link=$(this);
   $.ajax({
      url: "/InMail/check",
      type: "POST",
      data: { id: link.attr("data-id"), un: link.attr("data-un") }
   })
//handle .done, .fail and etc.
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much on implementation, i get link.attr is not a function can you help further?

Comment: the double quotes was the culprit your solution works when edited.  I have edited that so that I can accept your answer.  I found other ways around this also but thanks for your prompt assistance.